# Exogenous variable in a state equation in DLM package in R

Tags: r, regression, kalman-filter, dlm

I am trying to estimate the following state space model with the `dlm` package in R:

```
Y_t = theta_t + beta * x_t + e_t where e_t ~ N(0, sigma_e)
theta_t = alpha + lambda * theta_{t-1} + gamma * x_t + w_t 
                                                   where w_t ~ N(0, sigma_w)
```

I have two questions on the estimating and forecasting this general `ARMAX` model in the `dlm` package.

- ***Can I estimate this model using the `dlm` package in R?*** I have not been able to find any examples that show how to model the exogenous variable in the state equation. This makes it different from `dlmModReg` where exogenous variables only in the measurement equation is allowed (as per my understanding). I do have Petris's DLM book.
- I could possibly estimate the parameters in some other package such as `MARSS`, though I would prefer to stick to the `dlm` package. Still I would like to input those estimates into the `dlm` package to be able to generate forecasts with `dlmForecast`. ***Hence, my question is how do I  create a `dlm` object from those externally obtained estimates, that could then be used with `dlmForecast`?***

Would appreciate any insights on these questions.

Cheers,

Raghu.

Comment: Is that code in your code block or just an equation? What's the slash before the `lambda`? Could you give a reproducible example?

Comment: These are just equations. I have removed the slash before lambda. I am seeking a reproducible example of this equation in the dlm package.

Comment: FYI, it would be easy to fit this model with `MARSS::MARSS()`.